# Algolia per session index settings?

Tags: indexing, algolia

I have a collection where I'm allowing users to add or remove fields through a configuration and would like to index and search that collection with Algolia.

To do this I'm doing is calling `setStettings` on my index with the user-specific `searchableAttributes`, `numericAttributesForFiltering`, and `attributesForFaceting` when they log in.

This seems to work in testing, but I'm not really sure what I'm doing with that call. Is that `setSettings` call specifying the settings for that instance of the index, only affecting subsequent `search` calls in that session? Or is it resetting the index settings in Algolia itself, affecting all users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will reset the settings for the given index directly on the cluster, "in Algolia itself".

You can find a list of parameters overridable at query time (with the `search` tag) here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript/settings/#index-settings-parameters